# How to run batch file as an elevated user?

Tags: windows, batch-file, user-accounts, elevated-privileges

I have a batch file that creates another user using this code:

```
net user /add TheAccount passWORD
net localgroup administrators TheAccount /add
```

And I did this so that my program would later run commands elevated **without the UAC popping up**, because it could use its own account...

But I hit a roadblock when I noticed that `RunAs` doesn't allow elevation.

I really need to be able to run a program elevated *without* any third-party tools that I would have to include.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129136/discussion-on-question-by-cascading-style-how-to-run-batch-file-as-an-elevated-u).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, but I found an answer with [Microsoft Psexec.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074372/6939690) with the `-h` option or the
`-s` option.

Comment: Unless anybody has any other ideas...?